# Create an object with properties that are keys of static strings from a class

Tags: typescript

This may not be possible in TypeScript, but I'll ask anyways.

Say I have an base service class:

```
export default class Service {
  public static readonly accessorName: string

  constructor(protected prisma: PrismaClient, protected services: ServiceMap) {}
}
```

and I have a bunch of classes that extend it:

```
export default class Users extends Service {
  public static readonly accessorName = "users"
}

export default class Warehouses extends Service {
  public static readonly accessorName = "warehouses"
}

export default class Depots extends Service {
  public static readonly accessorName = "depots"
}
```

I'd like to create an object that is statically typed but looks like this:

```
type ServiceMap = {
  users: Users
  warehouses: Warehouses
  depots: Depots
}
```

Note that the key in `ServiceMap` is the `accessorName` coming from each individual class.

The closest I was able to get to this was to create a module and export the classes:

```
import Users from "./Users"
import Warehouses from "./Warehouses"
import Depots from "./Depots"

export { Users, Warehouses, Depots }
```

And then create a `ServiceMap` module that imports the services from the module as namespace.

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client"
import * as services from "./services"
import { Service } from "./services/Service"

type Services = typeof services

export type ServiceMap = {
  [S in keyof Services]: InstanceType<Services[S]>
}

export default function createServiceMap(prisma: PrismaClient) {
  const map: Partial<ServiceMap> = {}

  Object.values(services).map(
    (s: typeof Service) => (map[s.name as keyof ServiceMap] = new s(prisma, map as ServiceMap))
  )

  return map as ServiceMap
}
```

But the type it creates is actually:

```
type ServiceMap = {
  Users: Users
  Warehouses: Warehouses
  Depots: Depots
}
```

Additionally `map[s.name as keyof ServiceMap]` brings back:

```
Type 'Service' is not assignable to type 'Users & Warehouses & Depots'.
```

I'd like to use the `accessorName` for the keys for `ServiceMap` if possible. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the key renaming feature of mapped types.

For example:

```
type Foo = { a: string, b: string }
type Bar = { [K in keyof Foo as `get${Uppercase<K>}`]: Foo[K] }
// Bar is { getA: string, getB: string }
```

So in your case, you can do the same, but just drill into `accessorName`.

```
const services = { Users, Warehouses, Depots }
type Services = typeof services

type ServiceMap = {
  [S in keyof Services as Services[S]['accessorName']]: InstanceType<Services[S]>
}
```

And now this works:

```
function createServiceMap(prisma: PrismaClient) {
  const map: Partial<ServiceMap> = {}
  // TODO: implementation
  return map as ServiceMap
}

const map = createServiceMap(prisma)
map.depots // Depots
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKBDAXFAzsAJwEsA7AcwBooAjHfY8qAXwChRIoAhDA5NKANoBpKKSgBrCCDgAzWAky4oAAzIRgAElQBVMJAIBjDLggAeIQD4mygLo54cYTeYtX7aAAViuALYYAwgA2RBAkwHzoYMQ+uNhQhACu0ExQAPSpeMAJ1K4GgcZKAMoQBABuRAbQqCxQUGDZwQaZGMAVUAQQGAAmcCSBIJgGlbi4cAQAchg+EHSEpGSutQa99AkGwGMAFFFwwBDrEF113n44XkS+AcGhwFQ7ewdHJmUVELg4xS+VALIYYACUaFYrBYeQKUG0zyUEAAHnsSF0iiVypU0DU6g02vgWm0Ot1ev1BsNRhMptAUAAiBJQiksEFgkZQADqPAgAAs4NS3lBYfDEVBPiiquj6tRGs1Wk08T0+gMMEM3iTJtM+BSAO6sjlc3C0+n5RkAEQgYF20LhoX5gteaNqovF2Ml7U6MsJ8uJY2V5KgFK6xtNutyK3CzyFShQ6EhJVwVBZHS1JmjUCNJuASlY7gFyNeYfi4AgsjwWeGbjzma+EF+YAi6IEhVEJAkUgLVuGijLodrNgEAHI3YqPWTuzY7FAAJIkbEkSoAFTzphbb07FjprhkCSnrV6UAMeL2C8r2xOcXOlyCITCgOqSyDUD8YDOPFaGEC86LFb+FgirFq6VEPjAgQQNMYQ4r06IdFkBANnebb7n8K6gjeMEoDunR7m+B6oFERAxHEiQQEw-wsHeAB0vopkov7JqaQA)

Comment: This is awesome!!! I was trying something similar but I didn't land on your solution.

Comment: I'm wondering how I can now assign it to the object? I'm getting: `Type 'Users' is not assignable to type 'Warehouse | Depot | undefined'.
    Type 'Users' is missing the following properties from type 'Warehouse': name, includes, update, forDepot`.

Comment: You just assign it https://tsplay.dev/NB4VkW the only place you have do the extra cast is on `map` because its not entirely built yet, which means the constructor shouldn't be using that map.